# checkbox states disappear on pagination of kendo grid

Tags: checkbox, pagination, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Not sure if I am doing this correctly. But I bind a kendo grid with array data of objects, where each object has a Boolean property (i.e. either true or false).

For the user I display it as a checkbox with the checked state showing the `true` state and vice versa. If you check something in the page 1; go to the page 3; check a few rows; and go back to page 1, the state of the checkbox defaults to how it was at the time it was loaded.

Here is the code snippet I've used.

```
$(function () {
    var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '/echo/json/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    json: JSON.stringify(students)                    
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 5
    });

    var kgrid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [

        {
            field: 'name',
            title: 'Name'
        }, {
            field: 'age',
            title: 'Age'
        }, {
            field: 'place',
            title: 'Place'
        }, {
            field: 'hasCar',
            title: 'Owns Car',
            template: function (data) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" ' + (data.hasCar ? 'checked' : '') + '/>';
            }
        }],
        height: 240,
        pageable: true
    });

    $('#btnload').click(function () {
        var grid = kgrid.data('kendoGrid');
        grid.setDataSource(ds);
        $('#grid-display').show();
    });

    $('#btnrefresh').click(function(){
       ds.read(); 
       console.log('refresh'); 
    });

    $('#btnlist').click(function(){
        var res = $('#result');
        kgrid.find('tr td:last input:checked').each(function(i, e){
           var name = $(e).closest('tr').children().first().text();
           res.append('<p>' + name + '</p>'); 
           console.log('execute');           
        });
    });
});
```

How to persist the state on pagination?

Ps: fiddle to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/2SGyV/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the changes you are doing stays there in the grid only - not in `kendoDataSource`. Here `MVVM` is not done. So you have to change appropriate value in `dataSource` each time you click the `checkbox`.

When you select another page in `kendoGrid`, it fetches data from `dataSource`, and then display it the grid. Unless and untill `that` `dataSource` is changed, you can't see the changes done in the grid.

PS: Had there is any field for `Id` in `dataSource` I would have updated *jsfiddle* myself

***UPDATE***

Check this **[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2SGyV/4/)**

I have updated template for checkbox

```
template: function (data) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" ' + (data.hasCar ? 'checked' : '') + ' data-name="'+ data.name + '"' +'/>';
}
```

Now checkbox will have `name` of the data. You can change it with `id`. On change event, update your `dataSource` accordingly on each checkbox click.

```
$('#grid-display input').live('change', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('data-name'));
    //update the data source here based on the data-name attribute u're getting
});
```

Comment: any declarative way of doing this? Like adding `data-bind` syntaxes?

Answer (score 0):

Use databound event in the kendo Grid.

Not sure below code work will work for you or not. But similar code worked for me

```
function OnDataBoundEventMethod(e) {
    var view = this.dataSource.view();
    for (var i = 0; i < view.length; i++) {
        if ([view[i].hasCar]) {
            this.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + view[i].uid + "']")
                .addClass("k-state-selected")
                .find(".row-check-box")
                .attr("checked", "checked");
        }
    }
}
```